# How to reverse a clip on kdenlive

Tags: video-editing, kdenlive

I'm using Kdenlive v17.12.3 and am trying to reverse a video clip, i.e. play it backwards. [Previously](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1g5_ZMrIqwg), this could be done via 'clip jobs' in the context menu of the respective clip. But this feature has disappeared in my version. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a simple way to do what you want: under `Clip Jobs` select `Duplicate clip with speed change`:-

[image: KDEnliveSelect]

Now specify the speed as **`-100%`**:-

[image: KDEnliveSpeed]

Note that this will create a new clip, with `.mlt` appended to the original clip path.

Answer (score 8):

Kdenlive 19, has the following option, when selecting a clip in the timeline:

[image]

Then simply click the reverse clip checkbox

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @afh answer, you can also provide a negative value to the `speed` effect in order to reverse a video without duplicating the clip.

- `-100%` will revert the clip
- `-200%` will revert the clip and x2 the speed